Jenkins : Build is failing after "Build success" message in console output
I am running a test automation code built on Selenium Java with Maven on Jenkins.
While running the build, the test automation script works as expected and is passing.
However, after test execution, I get the following error message which changes the build outcome to "Failure" :
Parsing POMs
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  34.440 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-08-20T11:05:17+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parsing POMs
FATAL: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/ClassWorldListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.ClassWorldListener
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)

I tried executing a Maven project on Jenkins.
I was expecting a successful build status if the test case passed.
What happened was that I got a "Finished : Failure" message.

There are several Jenkins configuration options that can affect build status, related to factors like Error Level, Pre- and Post-Build execution command failure, artifacts archive and so on. More on Build step: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/
You may need to check for your project configuration for such options to be able to set whether the Jenkins Job shall report a failure for any of these possibilities. Given the error log in your question, my best advice would be to either fix it or set the error log level below this threshold to keep the build as stable (passing) even with this present.

As stated, this may be a cause of failure but not the only cause, so also look out for the properness of the remaining settings to keep the overall build status in green.
